# Why is jQuery not correctly toggling between iframes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet that adds a fixed div to the page, and should toggle between iframes when I click on specific buttons. I use jQuery for the button activation, but it isn't working.

here is the code injecting jQuery:

```
var x = document.createElement('script');
x.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js';
document.body.appendChild(x);
```

here is the code adding the div:

```
var lol = document.createElement('div');
lol.id = "desmos";
lol.style.background = 'blue';
lol.style.position = 'fixed';
lol.style.width = '30%';
lol.style.height = '50%';
lol.style.top = '40%';
lol.style.left = '70%';
lol.innerHTML = "<style>body{color: white;}</style>toggle iframes <button id='button'>1</button> <button id='button2'>2</button> <button id='button3'>3</button> <iframe id='iframe' src='https://desmos.com/calculator'></iframe> <iframe id='iframe2' src='https://desmos.com/scientific'></iframe> <iframe id='iframe3' src='https://desmos.com/geometry'></iframe>";
document.body.appendChild(lol);
```

and here is the code that uses jQuery to switch between iframes:

```
  $("#iframe").hide();
  $("#iframe2").hide();

  $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#iframe").show();
    $("#iframe2").hide();
    $("#iframe3").hide();
  });
  $("#button2").click(function() {
    $("#iframe2").show();
    $("#iframe").hide();
    $("#iframe3").hide();
  });
  $("#button3").click(function() {
    $("#iframe3").show();
    $("#iframe2").hide();
    $("#iframe").hide();
  });
```

Comment: not sure how a bookmarklet is using `$("document").ready(function() {` since page has probably already loaded by the time you click the book mark. Do you find the buttons/iframes? `console.log` is your friend here to debug.

Comment: I am on a school computer, and the console is disabled. I will remove $("document").ready();

Comment: ok, that seems to have fixed it